# how does low frequency react when its hits hard surface like concrete wall?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

I heard low frequency sound tends to pass through barrier whose wavelength is longer than depth of the barrier.
1. What happens when 20-30 hz sound hits the wall, does it reflect, absorbed or transmitted?

Comment: -1. No research effort.

Comment: Despite your personalisation of it, the structure and "1" in your question suggest this is a homework-like exercise. I have added the homework tag. You need to show some effort and ask about what you are finding difficult. ... Where does the barrier come into the question? It suggests diffraction is involved.

Answer (score 1):

> **What happens when 20-30 hz sound hits the wall, does it reflect, absorbed or transmitted?**

Yes.

<sub>*All three, in proportions which depend on the characteristics of the wall.*</sub>

E.g.

- [TRANSMISSION OF SOUND THROUGH STRUCTURES](http://www.mne.psu.edu/lamancusa/me458/9_trans.pdf)